# Getting count from 2 table and group by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I had 2 tables here with same structure basically. Here's the structure.

```
---------------------------
| Table In                 
---------------------------
| Id    | Date
---------------------------
| 1     | 2013-05-22
| 2     | 2013-07-20
---------------------------


---------------------------
| Table Out                 
---------------------------
| Id    | Date
---------------------------
| 1     | 2013-05-20
| 2     | 2013-06-21
| 3     | 2013-07-24
---------------------------
```

I just want to count this data and the expected results is :

```
----------------------------------------------
| month   | countin       | countout
----------------------------------------------
| 5       | 1             | 1
| 6       | 0             | 1
| 7       | 1             | 1
```

But, when I try with this query :

```
SELECT month(date) AS `month`, count(*) AS `countin`,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `out`
        WHERE month(date) = `month`) AS `countout`
FROM `in`
GROUP BY `month`
```

The result is :

```
----------------------------------------------
| month   | countin       | countout
----------------------------------------------
| 5       | 1             | 1
| 7       | 1             | 1
```

Please help me.

Comment: The problem of your result is that in the table `in` there is not a single record about June so  you are just selecting the information about May and July fromthe table `out`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join both tables with month:

```
SELECT MONTH(I.date) AS `month`
     , COUNT(I.ID) AS `countin`
     , COUNT(O.ID) AS `countOUT`
  FROM TableIN I
 LEFT JOIN TableOUT O
    ON MONTH(I.Date) = MONTH(O.Date)
 GROUP BY MONTH(I.date)
UNION
SELECT MONTH(O.date) AS `month`
     , COUNT(I.ID) AS `countin`
     , COUNT(O.ID) AS `countOUT`
  FROM TableIN I
 RIGHT JOIN TableOUT O
    ON MONTH(I.Date) = MONTH(O.Date)
 GROUP BY MONTH(I.date);
```

Result:

```
| MONTH | COUNTIN | COUNTOUT |
------------------------------
|     5 |       1 |        1 |
|     7 |       1 |        1 |
|     6 |       0 |        1 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b967b5/12)

Also to order your result by month you need to use a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(I.date) AS `month`
         , COUNT(I.ID) AS `countin`
         , COUNT(O.ID) AS `countOUT`
      FROM TableIN I
     LEFT JOIN TableOUT O
        ON MONTH(I.Date) = MONTH(O.Date)
     GROUP BY MONTH(I.date)
    UNION
    SELECT MONTH(O.date) AS `month`
         , COUNT(I.ID) AS `countin`
         , COUNT(O.ID) AS `countOUT`
      FROM TableIN I
     RIGHT JOIN TableOUT O
        ON MONTH(I.Date) = MONTH(O.Date)
     GROUP BY MONTH(I.date)
    ) tbl
ORDER BY Month;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b967b5/23)

Comment: And where is month `June` in your result?

Comment: @FSou1 - Yes you are correct. Now updated the answer with `FULL JOIN`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select months.mnth,cntin,cntout from
(select month(date) as mnth from TableOUT
union select month(date) as mnth from TableIN) months
left join 
(SELECT month(date) as mnth,count(*) as cntin
        FROM `TableIN` group by month(date)) mntin
on mntin.mnth = months.mnth
left join 
(SELECT month(date) as mnth,count(*) as cntout
        FROM `TableOUT` group by month(date)) mntout
on mntout.mnth = months.mnth
;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51df4/11)

Comment: This can solve the problem if in the table out there are at least 1 record for each month. If it's the same as the table `in`, where you miss record for a month, you'll have the same problem.

Comment: `a + b != b + a`? You think its solution, when next time it won't be month `June` in out?

Comment: this is only a reverse version of case. it doesnt help

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support outer joins so this gets a bit messy:

```
select ifnull(inmonth, outmonth) as month, countin, countout
from 
(
  Select in.month as inmonth, out.month as outmonth, 
    in.countin as countin, out.countout as countout
  from 
    (select month(`date`) as `month`, count(*) as `countin` from `in` group by month(`date`)) `in`
  left join
    (select month(`date`) as `month`, count(*) as `countout` from `out` group by month(`date`)) `out`
    on in.month=out.month
UNION
 select in.month as inmonth, out.month as outmonth, 
    in.countin as countin, out.countout as countout
  from 
    (select month(`date`) as `month`, count(*) as `countin` from `in` group by month(`date`)) `in`
  right join
    (select month(`date`) as `month`, count(*) as `countout` from `out` group by month(`date`)) `out`
  on in.month=out.month
) as foo
```

If the table names are transaction_in and transaction_out then change

```
from `in`
```

to

```
from `transaction_in`
```

And so with the `out`s.

Comment: how if the table name transaction_in and transaction_out. Sorry, I dont understand how to read your query. I'm a newbie.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

The row 6 does not exists in table in, so you cannot join like you did without restricting data.

I suggest this approach (no need of any outer join !) :

```
SELECT month,sum(countin),sum(countout) FROM (
SELECT month(date) AS `month`,count(1) AS `countin`,0  AS `countout`
FROM TableIN `in`
GROUP BY `month`
UNION
SELECT month(date) AS `month`,0 `countin`,count(1)  AS `countout`
FROM TableOUT `out`
GROUP BY `month`
) `test`
GROUP BY month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b967b5/28

And maybe you could look at some outer join mechanisms also.
Details can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)